# Dijkstra's algorithm with Gremlin

Tags: dijkstra, orientdb, gremlin

I want to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in Gremlin to create a fully-meshed graph containing the shortest paths only.

I'm using Gremlin on top of an OrientDB database. Since the shortest path algorithm in Furnace is not implemented yet, I need to implement it by myself. I understand the basic workings of Gremlin, but I'm currently stuck with it.

I could also write it in Java, but I need the flexibility of a Gremlin solution. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/issues/144. It uses Neo4J but OrientDB implements the same API, so it's identical.

Comment: Luca, thanks for your answer! I would like to have the algorithm implemented with Gremlin only without depending on Jung or other additional libraries. I'd like to see how well it can perform. Thank you for your answer though. I still wonder why Furnace doesn't seem to make progress ...

Comment: Probably the best place to ask it is the Gremlin ML. However writing it from scratch should be not so hard: http://en.literateprograms.org/Dijkstra's_algorithm_(Java). In case you write it let me know to include in the OrientDB distribution